# Allow catalogs to be accessed from only certain workspaces - Databricks

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

According to [this wonderful bog post](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2023/03/09/distributed-data-governance-and-isolated-environments-unity-catalog.html), it should be possible to restrict access to a catalog from only certain workspaces i.e. this section

[image]

However, when I look at the terraform samples [here](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/12/08/automated-guide-distributed-and-decentralized-management-unity-catalog.html)
and the create catalog options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-catalogs), I do not see any option which shows how to do this.

Is it still in preview and not really GA? Azure is the cloud provider in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is now available in Databricks (Azure at least).

Go to Data, then find the catalog and you see a "Workspaces" tab.

In that screen, you untick the option "All workspaces have access" and assign it to the specific workspace.

We use this to assign environment specific catalog to their corresponding workspaces (i.e DEV, TEST and PROD).

[image]

Comment: Aah cool, I too can see it now :)

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is still in the private preview - if you want to use it, please contact your Databricks representative to enable it for your environment.

Update, May 2023rd: This functionality is released, and now you [can assign catalog only to specific workspace(s)](https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-catalogs.html#optional-assign-a-catalog-to-specific-workspaces).

Comment: I have been using this functionality and it allows you to limit specific catalogs to specific workspaces. However, it does not limit access to External Locations, which can be a security flaw.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Can you elaborate a bit more? If you mean a storage location, like you can register an external location , like Azure Data Lake Gen 2, to be allowed access from only one workspace, that should be governed by someone/process that manages approvals for the datalake. That I don't think unity catalog can govern.

Comment: @alexott:  I see it is only available through the GUI and rest API. Do we know if the same functionality would soon be available through Terraform (mentioned in my original question) ?

Comment: There is a work in progress for Terraform